# How can I locate and measure this object in the picture?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have this image
Interest in detecting the long structure from the first image and the expected results are attached in the next image.

The expected results

I have tried the following procedures

1. thresholding
2. contour detection
3. alignment of the binary image to the horizontal (use the angle of rotation)
4. Advice needed `Next from step 3` because my codes can detect the whole object but not the structure of interest

Here are my codes

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
iterations = 7
img00 = cv2.imread('./camera1'+str(a)+'.jpg')
gray00 = cv2.cvtColor(img00, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

median_blur1 = cv2.medianBlur(gray00, iterations) # smoothing with median blur
ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(median_blur1,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) # binarization with Otsu
# External Contour detection 
contours1, hierarchy1 = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
try:
    cnt1 = contours1[0]
except IndexError: # Suppressing the index error to keep the camera live
    pass
# Getting the biggest contour
if len(contours1) != 0:
    # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
    c1 = max(contours1, key = cv2.contourArea)

height, width = img00.shape[:2]
center = (width/2, height/2)
x1,y1,w1,h1 = cv2.boundingRect(thresh1)
rect1 = cv2.minAreaRect(c1)
print(rect1[2])
rotate_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center=center, angle=rect1[2], scale=1)
binary_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(src=thresh1, M=rotate_matrix, dsize=(width, height))

contours2, hierarchy2 = cv2.findContours(binary_rotated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt2 = contours2[0]


x2,y2,w2,h2 = cv2.boundingRect(binary_rotated)
rect2 = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt2)
box2 = cv2.boxPoints(rect2)
box2

cv2.drawContours(binary_rotated, [box2], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.drawContours(img00, [box2], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('image', img00)
cv2.imshow('rotated_image', binary_rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: your title doesn't match the question. is your question about how to draw rectangles, or about how to measure this thing in your picture?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. If drawing a rectangle will be possible or easy then, we can easily measure the length and width of the middle (long structure/member). I hope I am understood now.

Comment: get mask. get oriented bounding box. apply lengthwise measurement lines at around 25 and 75% into the "width" of the box. measure thickness of end pieces. at 50%, measure length of entire piece. subtract thickness of end pieces. or skip that, take the center length, and get your midpoint from that. mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiemT.png

Comment: I think this is the step where I have failed for several times if possible explain in detail. I have all points on a rectangle but I need some mathematics to find those 25 and 75 of the width or otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach:

- `minAreaRect` from convex hull
- some geometry to establish a *local coordinate system*
- taking 1-D samples along the object (`warpAffine`)
- finding edges to measure thickness of bars

To get the midpoint of the center bar *exactly*, you'd want to go along the object halfway, then scan crosswise for the center bar.

There may be some off-by-one errors in all of this, where I look for indices. You get the idea though.

I haven't bothered implementing a *local maxima* function, although that would make the results more accurate. I just pick the index of the first gradient element that's above a threshold. The local maximum probably encompasses multiple elements.

One of my favorite Non-Maximum Suppression approaches, for 2D, is to use dilation (morphology operation) to suppress local non-maxima. `cv.dilate` would be an option, or `scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_dilation`. That ought to be followed up by connected components labeling because two adjacent elements may both be local maxima, when they're equal, and you wouldn't want both of them to count, but their centroid.

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
# utility defs for later

norm = np.linalg.norm

def normalize(vec):
    return vec / norm(vec)
```

```
# read picture, binarize
im = cv.imread('aXrEv.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im = im[:, 100:-150] # debris in the top right corner

(level, mask) = cv.threshold(im, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
# imshow(mask)
```

```
# get hull
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hull = cv.convexHull(np.concatenate(contours))
print(len(hull), "points in convex hull")

canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.drawContours(canvas, [hull], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
imshow(canvas)
```

[image: hull]

```
# get box
# oriented bounding box
rrect = cv.minAreaRect(hull)
print(rrect) # (cx,cy), (w,h), angle

box = cv.boxPoints(rrect)

# roll corners so 0-1 is long edge
if norm(box[1] - box[0]) < norm(box[2] - box[1]):
    box = np.roll(box, 1, axis=0)

print(box)

canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.drawContours(canvas, [box.astype(int)], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
for i,pt in enumerate(box):
    cv.putText(canvas,
        f"[{i}]", (pt + [-10, 10]).astype(int),
        cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.8, (255, 186, 0), thickness=2)
imshow(canvas)
```

[image: box and corners]

```
# local coordinate system

# assuming long edge is corner 0-1
orig = box[0].copy()
box_length = box[1] - orig
box_width = box[3] - orig
print("orig", orig)
print("vx", box_length)
print("vy", box_width)

vx = normalize(box_length)
vy = normalize(box_width)

# extend the box a little
orig -= 1*vx
box_length += 2*vx

canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.arrowedLine(canvas, orig.astype(int), (orig + box_length).astype(int), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv.arrowedLine(canvas, orig.astype(int), (orig + box_width).astype(int), (0, 255, 0), 2)
imshow(canvas)
```

[image: local coordinate system]

```
# more coordinates
# sample lines along long edge, one center and two offset to each side
orig_25 = orig + box_width * 0.25
orig_50 = orig + box_width * 0.50
orig_75 = orig + box_width * 0.75
```

```
def sample_line(im, p1, p2, ustep=1, vwidth=1):
    "take sample along line between points, 1D or 2D"
    # vstep: exercise for the reader
    origin = np.array(p1)
    vec = p2 - p1
    ulength = int(round(np.linalg.norm(vec) / ustep)) + 1
    uvec = normalize(vec) * ustep
    vvec = np.array([-uvec[1], uvec[0]])

    if vwidth > 1:
        origin -= vvec * (vwidth - 1) / 2

    # build affine transform, backwards
    M = np.eye(3)
    M[0:2, 2] = origin
    M[0:2, 0] = uvec
    M[0:2, 1] = vvec
    assert np.allclose(M[2], [0, 0, 1])

    samples = cv.warpAffine(im, M[:2], (ulength, vwidth), flags=cv.INTER_LINEAR | cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
    if vwidth == 1:
        samples = samples.squeeze(axis=0)
    return samples
```

```
# taking 1-D samples
samples_25 = sample_line(mask, orig_25, orig_25 + box_length)
samples_50 = sample_line(mask, orig_50, orig_50 + box_length)
samples_75 = sample_line(mask, orig_75, orig_75 + box_length)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(15, 15))
axes[0].plot(samples_25)
axes[1].plot(samples_50)
axes[2].plot(samples_75)
plt.show()
```

[image: relief plots]

```
grad_25 = np.gradient(samples_25)
grad_50 = np.gradient(samples_50)
grad_75 = np.gradient(samples_75)

# find edges...

# center line: first rising edge, last falling edge
center_i0 = (grad_50 >= 50).argmax()
center_i1 = len(samples_50) - (grad_50[::-1] <= -50).argmax()
print("total length:", center_i1 - center_i0)

# lower bar: first rising, first falling edge
lower_left_i0 = (grad_25 >= +50).argmax()
lower_left_i1 = (grad_25 <= -50).argmax()
lower_right_i0 = (grad_75 >= +50).argmax()
lower_right_i1 = (grad_75 <= -50).argmax()
lower_bar_width = ((lower_right_i1 - lower_right_i0) + (lower_left_i1 - lower_left_i0)) / 2
print("lower bar:",
    "left", lower_left_i1 - lower_left_i0,
    "right", lower_right_i1 - lower_right_i0,
    "avg", lower_bar_width)


# upper bar: last falling, last rising
upper_left_i0 = (grad_25[::-1] <= -50).argmax() # last falling edge
upper_left_i1 = (grad_25[::-1] >= +50).argmax() # last rising edge
upper_right_i0 = (grad_75[::-1] <= -50).argmax()
upper_right_i1 = (grad_75[::-1] >= +50).argmax()
upper_bar_width = ((upper_right_i1 - upper_right_i0) + (upper_left_i1 - upper_left_i0)) / 2
print("upper bar:",
    "left", upper_left_i1 - upper_left_i0,
    "right", upper_right_i1 - upper_right_i0,
    "avg", upper_bar_width)

print("center segment:", (center_i1 - center_i0) - lower_bar_width - upper_bar_width)
```

```
total length: 664
lower bar: left 26 right 29 avg 27.5
upper bar: left 24 right 28 avg 26.0
center segment: 610.5
```

```
def line_with_endbars(img, pt1, pt2, barLength=20, *args, **kwargs):
    "draw line with end bars"
    pt1 = np.asarray(pt1)
    pt2 = np.asarray(pt2)

    cv.line(img, pt1.astype(int), pt2.astype(int), *args, **kwargs)

    (vx, vy) = normalize(pt2 - pt1)
    n = np.array([-vy, vx])

    cv.line(img, (pt1 - n/2 * barLength).astype(int), (pt1 + n/2 * barLength).astype(int), *args, **kwargs)
    cv.line(img, (pt2 - n/2 * barLength).astype(int), (pt2 + n/2 * barLength).astype(int), *args, **kwargs)
```

```
# draw that info
canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

color = (255, 186, 0)

# lower bar, left/right
cv.line(canvas,
    (orig_25 + lower_left_i0 * vx).astype(int),
    (orig_25 + lower_left_i1 * vx).astype(int),
    color=color, thickness=2)

cv.line(canvas,
    (orig_75 + lower_right_i0 * vx).astype(int),
    (orig_75 + lower_right_i1 * vx).astype(int),
    color=color, thickness=2)

# upper bar, left/right
cv.line(canvas,
    (orig_25 + box_length - upper_left_i0 * vx).astype(int),
    (orig_25 + box_length - upper_left_i1 * vx).astype(int),
    color=color, thickness=2)

cv.line(canvas,
    (orig_75 + box_length - upper_right_i0 * vx).astype(int),
    (orig_75 + box_length - upper_right_i1 * vx).astype(int),
    color=color, thickness=2)

# center bar minus end bars
subject_e0 = orig_50 + vx * (center_i0 + lower_bar_width)
subject_e1 = orig_50 + vx * (center_i1 - upper_bar_width)

print("subject length:", np.linalg.norm(subject_e1 - subject_e0))

# draw subject
# cv.line(canvas,
#     subject_e0.astype(int),
#     subject_e1.astype(int),
#     (0, 186, 0), 2)

line_with_endbars(canvas, subject_e0, subject_e1, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

#imshow(canvas)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for this answer it is helpful but I want to ask you more when I apply the same algorithm to the other 3 different images it appears to draw a line parallel to, and below the one at the center of the canvas. What might be the problem here?

Comment: you need to provide that data then. nobody can debug your issue if you don't provide the data that causes the issue.

Comment: well, how are things? I tried to help...

Comment: You helped me so much, Can I add you 3 - 5 images for debugging? If it is okay, inform me how I can share the pictures, I keep on saying thank you for your extended help. Sorry for being late in responding to your comments.

Comment: you can add them to your question. just edit it and insert the pictures.